# Skip line in config parser if character is # commented with fscanf

Tags: c, config, configparser

I've written a simple config parser using `fscanf` and now want to add a comment character (`#`).

My configuration file contains three columns of which `fscanf` reads and stores in their corresponding arrays. This works well, but I'm a little unsure how to write it so that "if the character read is `#` then move onto the next line.

I've tried using `fgetc` but that seems to only read the first character, and it appears to break the logic within my while loop.

I've tried using a modification of `"%*[^\n]\n"` in my fscanf as:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%d\t%f\t%f%*[^#]\n", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i]) != EOF)
```

but that causes a seg fault.

Config:

```
#hello and welcome to my config file
1666    -0.314913523    0.999804843        #blah blah
1667    -0.337279687    0.999865966
1703    -0.323162231    0.999774194
1704    -0.311984064    0.99964375
1705    -0.311984064    0.99964375
1706    -0.313381260    0.999671436
1707    -0.313170802    0.999558174
```

Code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_ITEMS 50

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("config.conf","r");

    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("No file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int a[NUM_ITEMS];
    float b[NUM_ITEMS];
    float c[NUM_ITEMS];

    int i = 0;

    while(fscanf(fp,"%d\t%f\t%f", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i]) != EOF)
    {
        printf("-> %d   %f  %f\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` is not good for consuming variable input. Use `fgets` to read each line and then `sscanf` or other string based functions to parse. That will allow you to run multiple parse operations over the input.

Comment: I'd probably rework it to use `fgets()` to read lines and `sscanf()` to parse the data using the formats you currently use with `fscanf()`.  You can easily insert a test for and ignore comments between `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***fgets*** to read each line as a string and then check where *'#'* appears.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_ITEMS 50
#define MAX_CHAR 500

ssize_t find_index(char *str)
{
  size_t i=0U;

  for (; *str!='\0'; i++)
  {
    if (*str++=='#')
    {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[NUM_ITEMS];
  float b[NUM_ITEMS];
  float c[NUM_ITEMS];
  char buff[MAX_CHAR];
  FILE *fp;
  size_t i=0U;
  ssize_t index=0U;

  fp = fopen("config.conf","r");

  if(!fp)
  {
    printf("No file.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  while (fgets(buff,MAX_CHAR,fp))
  {
    index=find_index(buff);
    if (index!=-1)
    {
      buff[index]='\0'; /* Bare in mind this will skip the newline character which fgets appends */
    }

    if(sscanf(buff,"%d%f%f", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i])==3) /* Checking scanf read 3 numbers */
    {
      printf("-> %d %f %f\n", a[i], b[i], c[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So `find_index()` returns the location of the element **#** was found. Then replaced by ****NULL** terminator**.

As Jonathan pointed out in the comments, you can also use the `strcspn()` function along with `strlen()` (for error checking) to find the index of #.

Comment: There's a standard C function that does the job of `find_index()` — it's `strcspn()`, except that it returns the index of the null byte at the end of the string if the character is not found rather than returning `-1`.